# Setting Storyboard.Targetname on a storyboard defined as a static resource

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, staticresource

If I have a storyboard defined as a static resource eg:

```
<Storyboard
        x:Key="shakeAnimation"
    >
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.X" 
        RepeatBehavior="5x"
        >
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="3"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.20" Value="-3"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

</Storyboard>
```

and would like to apply somewhere I can do

```
<MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions >
     <BeginStoryboard>
         <StaticResource  
                         ResourceKey="shakeAnimation"/>
    </BeginStoryboard>
 </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
```

and it works I think. However if I want to appy the animation to a specific object then this doesn't work

```
<MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions >
     <BeginStoryboard>
         <StaticResource Storyboard.TargetName="editWidget"  
                         ResourceKey="shakeAnimation"/>
    </BeginStoryboard>
 </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
```

as I get error

> The attached property "TargetName" can only be applied to types that are derived from "DependencyObject".

Is there a neat way to store my storyboards as static resources and them apply them to elements as I would like?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're going to need to do this with a custom attached property. You would clone the `Storyboard`, and set the `TargetName` on the clone, and return it. Your class would look like this:

```
public static class NamedStoryboard
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StoryboardProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "Storyboard",
      typeof(Storyboard),
      typeof(NamedStoryboard),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DoAttach));

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(BeginStoryboard))]
    public static Storyboard GetStoryboard(BeginStoryboard obj)
    {
        return (Storyboard)obj.GetValue(StoryboardProperty);
    }

    public static void SetStoryboard(BeginStoryboard obj, Storyboard value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(StoryboardProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetNameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "TargetName",
      typeof(string),
      typeof(NamedStoryboard),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DoAttach));

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(BeginStoryboard))]
    public static string GetTargetName(BeginStoryboard obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(TargetNameProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTargetName(BeginStoryboard obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TargetNameProperty, value);
    } 

    private static void DoAttach(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var begin = d as BeginStoryboard;
        if (begin == null) return;

        var sb = GetStoryboard(begin);
        if (sb == null) return;

        var name = GetTargetName(begin);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            begin.Storyboard = sb;
        else
        {
            var clone = sb.Clone();
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(clone, name);
            begin.Storyboard = clone;
        }
    }
}
```

And you'd use it like so:

```
<BeginStoryboard local:NamedStoryboard.Storyboard="{StaticResource shakeAnimation}"
                 local:NamedStoryboard.TargetName="editWidget" />
```

Comment: If that works, buy yourself a beer tomorrow :) I was just thinking I might need to write a custom StoryBoard runner. Thanks for that

Comment: That works great. I had another question on SO recently about adding guards/conditions to storyboard. I suspect I could use this trick to do that too

Comment: Attached properties are a powerful way of extending behavior of elements in WPF. While they have been formalized as Blend behaviors, in some cases it is easier to just do it the old school way. Hopefully you can apply this technique to help you solve some more problems!